# Lightning Record Page

Tags: lightning, profile, page-layout, record-type, lightning-record-page

My mentor asked me this question,2 users with same profile, same page layout, same record type can see different fields based on their location. The answer is lightning record page, but how?

I have checked when you add the record detail component it doesn't allow you to edit the field and can't assign a particular field to any user or profile. Also, you can change visibility but it applied to all the profiles.

How can you achieve it?

Comment: Maybe like so: Go to Setup - User Interface - Lightning App Builder, click "New" and create a Record Page. Add a "Record Detail" to your page. Upgrade to "Dynamic Forms" and choose any layout as a boilerplate. Click on a field and configure a filter on the right side, "Filter Type" "Advanced". In "Select Field" choose User, choose City...

Answer (score 0):

In Lightning record page, You can upgrade that page into`Dynamic form`. Once it's upgraded. you can set the field visibility based on condition as follows,

```
Field Section >> Set component visibility >> Advanced >> Record >> Owner >> location/country.
```

So that you can show different Field section based on user's location/country.

Thanks.

Comment: Great!! Thank you for such a prompt response